# How much defragmentation can be achieved without a fresh zpool?

Tags: zfs

I have a zpool that was allowed to get very full, and heavily written while very full. It's back under 80% now, but some filesystems on it are still very slow.

I understand that to `zfs receive` those filesystems into a fresh pool would effectively defragment them. Let's say there isn't enough storage around for a fresh pool, but I could direct `zfs send` streams of several filesystems off onto a tape, destroy those filesystems in the pool, then `zfs receive` them into the pool again.

So my question is, would the same once-badly-fragmented zpool, if a big enough percentage of space (but not all of it) were freed by moving filesystems off, then have its free space well-enough coalesced that the same filesystems would be better allocated when received back into the pool? Could this achieve enough defragmentation to be worth the effort?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to know. If you're able to free enough of the pool that it would be very likely for there to be large contiguous regions (say 50%), then you could probably use the method you described. However, even with 50% of the disk free you could theoretically have every other block allocated, leading to the same level of fragmentation after the send.

The only way to guarantee this for sure is to migrate all the data to a new pool. If you're short on storage, you could also stand up an intermediate ZFS machine in the cloud just for this transfer, to avoid buying the disks yourself. This has the added benefit that if your send stream gets corrupted somehow, you can resend it rather than being SOL.